# How to solve an inconsistent system?

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

I'm new on MATLAB and I want to use it to solve an `Ax = b` system. I did this on paper and know I want to know if it's right. The problem is that it is an inconsistent system.

```
A=sym([3/sqrt(29) 3/sqrt(29) -1 0 0 0; 
1 -1 0 0 0 0; 
4/sqrt(29) 4/sqrt(29) 0 0 0 0; 
0 0 1 9/sqrt(101) 0 0; 
0 0 0 2/sqrt(101) -1/sqrt(5) 1/sqrt(5);
0 0 0 4/sqrt(101) 2/sqrt(5) 2/sqrt(5)])

c=sym([0 0 -a 0 0 -a])
```

When I tried finding the solution with:

```
A/c
```

I get:

```
Warning: The system is inconsistent. Solution does not exist.
```

I found many themes about that on the Internet, but there was no solution.  Does this mean that means MATLAB can't handle it or is there a way to get a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system is unfortunately not being solved properly.  You need to use the `ldivide` (`\`) operator, not `rdivide` (`/`).  Doing `A/c` is equivalent to `A*c^{-1}` and that's not what you want.  To solve for the solution to the system, you must do `A^{-1}*c` or equivalently `A\c`.  Also, in order to ensure that you get a proper solution, `c` needs to be a column vector, not a row vector.  I'm also assuming that `a` is a constant which isn't declared in the current code.

Therefore:

```
syms a; %// Added

A=sym([3/sqrt(29) 3/sqrt(29) -1 0 0 0; 
1 -1 0 0 0 0; 
4/sqrt(29) 4/sqrt(29) 0 0 0 0; 
0 0 1 9/sqrt(101) 0 0; 
0 0 0 2/sqrt(101) -1/sqrt(5) 1/sqrt(5);
0 0 0 4/sqrt(101) 2/sqrt(5) 2/sqrt(5)]);

c=sym([0 0 -a 0 0 -a]).'; %// Change

out = A\c;
```

I get:

```
out =

   -(29^(1/2)*a)/8
   -(29^(1/2)*a)/8
          -(3*a)/4
  (101^(1/2)*a)/12
    -(5^(1/2)*a)/4
 -(5*5^(1/2)*a)/12
```

Comment: Thx, so problem was me, I`m dump :D